# Erlang: How to make connected external OS process automatically die when controlling Erlang process crashes?

Tags: linux, erlang

I am using Erlang port to read output of Linux process. I'd like the Linux process to be automatically killed whenever my connected Erlang process dies. From the docs, it seems to me that this should automatically happen, but it does not.

Minimal example. Put this in the file test.erl:

```
-module(test).
-export([start/0, spawn/0]).

start() ->
    Pid = spawn_link(?MODULE, spawn, []),
    register(test, Pid).

spawn() ->
    Port = open_port({spawn, "watch date"},[stream, exit_status]),
    loop([{port, Port}]).

loop(State) ->
    receive
        die ->
            error("died");
        Any ->
            io:fwrite("Received: ~p~n", [Any]),
            loop(State)
    end.
```

Then, in erl shell:

```
1> c(test).
{ok,test}
2> test:start().
true
```

The process starts and prints some data received from the Linux "watch" command every 2 seconds.

Then, I make the Erlang process crash:

```
3> test ! die.
=ERROR REPORT==== 26-May-2021::13:24:01.057065 ===
Error in process <0.95.0> with exit value:
{"died",[{test,loop,1,[{file,"test.erl"},{line,15}]}]}

** exception exit: "died"
     in function  test:loop/1 (test.erl, line 15)
```

The Erlang process dies as expected, the data from "watch" stops appearing but the watch process still keeps running in the background as can be seen in Linux (not erl) terminal:

```
fuxoft@frantisek:~$ pidof watch
1880127
```

In my real-life scenario, I am not using "watch" command but other process that outputs data and accepts no input. How can I make it automaticall die when my connected Erlang process crashes? I can do this using Erlang supervisor and manually issuing the "kill" command when Erlang process crashes but I thought this could be done easier and cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

The `open_port` function creates a `port()` and links it to the calling process. If the owning process dies, the `port()` closes.

In order to communicate with the externally spawned command, Erlang creates several pipes, which are by default tied to the `stdin` and `stdout` (file descriptors) of the external process. Anything that the external process writes through the stdout will arrive as a message to the owning process.

When the `Port` is closed, the pipes attaching it to the external process are broken, and so trying to read or write to them will give you a SIGPIPE/EPIPE.

You can detect that from your external process when writing or reading from the FDs and exiting the process then.

E.g.: With your current code, you can retrieve the external process OS pid with `proplists:get_value(os_pid, erlang:port_info(Port))`. If you `strace` it, you will see:

```
write(1, ..., 38) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31297, si_uid=1001} ---
```

**SIGPIPE in ports and Erlang**

It seems that although the default action for SIGPIPE is to terminate the process, Erlang sets it to ignore the signal (and thus the children processes inherit this configuration).

If you're unable to modify the external process code to detect the EPIPE, you can use this c wrapper to reset the action:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL) == SIG_ERR)
        return 1;
    if (argc < 2)
        return 2;
    execv(argv[1], &(argv[1]));
}
```

just compile it and run it as `wrapper path-to-executable [arg1 [arg2 [...]]]` with `open_port`

Comment: I am not sure whether I don't understand you or you don't understand me but I don't see how this helps me. First, the external process was not written by me and I don't have its source code, so I cannot "write or read from the FDs used to communicate with Erlang". Second, when my Erlang process crashes during development, it brings down my whole app (all its processes are LINKed) so I cannot retrieve external process pid and do something with it - my whole app is already down. I understand that I could write extra independent Erlang process for that but I thought there is simpler solution.

Comment: @fuxoft I've edited the answer, I hope it's clearer now. If the external process does not exit when unable to print, you may need to write a wrapper for it. From the OS perspective, it's done everything it could (closing the file descriptors tying it to Erlang), it's up to the external process to recognize it and exit gracefully once it's no longer needed. In linux you could use the `prctl` call to have the external process killed on parent's death (but that would only work if the whole erlang node goes down with the port, which may or may not be your intentions), and you'd need the source.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. Your answer is "No, what you want cannot be done in Erlang, you have to write an OS wrapper for that"? In that case it seems simpler to write an extra Erlang process (not LINKed to all the others) that monitors all my Ports and kills the OS processes when they get disconnected.

Comment: @fuxoft More or less, yes. The problem with that approach (monitoring from erlang) is that if the external processes do not detect the EPIPE, they may live on in case of a node abrupt crash.

Comment: @fuxoft I've been looking a little more into this and I've added a very simple c wrapper that will reset the signal action and then `execv` away.

Comment: Note: The similar wrapper can be implemented in bash, without having to compile anything. See here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/port.ex#L132